# Storing invoices that may or may not be paid at the month they should be paid

Tags: c#, database

I need to develop a program in c# where users have to pay an invoice (with a fixed amount) every month. Some users might not pay the same month the invoice was sent to them, incurring overdue fees. The user should also be able to check the invoice online by some sort of ID. How should I approach this?

I have thought of two ways, but I don't find them very satisfying.

### Method one

I create a table where I store all of the invoices like so

```
+----+------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+
| Id | Code | CreatedOn | UserId | Amount |  PaidOn?   |
+----+------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+
|  1 | 1234 | 2018-04-1 |      1 | 100    | null       |
|  2 | 1235 | 2018-05-1 |      1 | 210*   | 2018-05-25 |
+----+------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+
```

*includes the previous amount, current amount, and an overdue fee.

In this instance I am caching the amount the user has to pay and generating a new invoice every month. The benefits of this approach are that when the user enters 1234, I can check the month and year do not match, and point them to the newest invoice they have to pay.

Also: Do I need some sort of service that generates these every month? Or whenever the administrator clicks the generate button, I do a check if an invoice already exists for a user, if not I insert it?

### Method two

I store only paid invoices. I can check when the last time an invoice was paid, and calculate the amount due from there. The problem however, is that I'm not sure how I should handle the code. Since an invoice will still be printed every first day of every month and sent to the users, so they need some sort of reference code.

One solution I thought was to have a GUID column on the users table, and use that guid to encrypt a date time of this format MMyyyy. The value generated will always be unique and I don't have to store it anywhere. So when the user enters the reference code, I decrypt the date and regenerate an invoice for them.

That's basically it, but for some reason both of these methods feel wrong.

Comment: How about combining this 2 methods? You can generate invoice in the begining of every month, notify user by email with link to this invoice, and on the next month (if invoice was not paid) you just update amount value and notify user again. You don't need some sort of service for this, just use some kind of scheduler (Cron, Windows Scheduler, Quartz.net etc.)

Comment: @vasily.sib Suggestions below advise against updating the old ones. Instead just create new ones every month. Thank you for the libraries provided, I'll use a mix of the answers here and from the info their accountant will provide to come up with a definite solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's correct to add the amount from previous unpaid invoices to new invoices, that's not how accounts payable works.  You issue new invoices for new items, and then if there are unpaid invoices you can issue a Statement showing that.

Method 2 is better, but I don't like the encrypted date idea.  I was once told by a boss that the tax authority expects invoice numbers to have sequential numbering (and that's how software like Quick Books works).  Also encrypted strings are going to be long and cumbersome.

Go with method 2 but use sequential invoice numbers and store all invoices, paid or not, I can't see a downside.

EDIT:

About overdue charges (by the way, the QB website is good for general book keeping Q&A, eg https://community.intuit.com/articles/1145979-can-i-enter-finance-charges-service-charges-or-late-fees-on-customer-invoices)

```
+----+------+-----------+--------+------------+------------+---------------+
| Id | Code | CreatedOn | UserId | LineAmount |  PaidOn?   | OtherCharges
+----+------+-----------+--------+------------+------------+---------------+
|  1 | 1234 | 2018-04-1 |      1 | 100        | null       |
|  2 | 1235 | 2018-05-1 |      1 | 100        | 2018-05-25 | 10
+----+------+-----------+--------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

I think it should look more like that (by the way, you should future proof it by assuming there will at some point be multiple LineAmounts, do that with a typical one to many relationship, but for simplicity assume only 1 here).

Invoice.Id==1 wasn't paid, so the 10 charge can go on Invoice.Id==2 (whose total is 110).

Customer still must pay Invoice 1, because Invoice 2 doesn't supersede it.

Comment: OK, so if I go with method two, say I store an invoice for this month, and the user doesn't pay, should I add a new column to store the overdue fees and on the next invoice, add the usual amount on the amount col, and the overdue amount on it's appropriate column? Once the final invoice is paid, I mark all as paid?

Comment: @E.Hoxha I added more to the answer

Comment: I thank you for your update. That link and your answer overall gave me a very neat idea on how to handle all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Treat things for what they are:

1. Invoice exists regardless if it was paid or not. That's another step in its lifetime. So, your database should reflect that fact.
2. Issue a real invoice for every period that user consumed and has to pay with the amount for that period. That is, at the end of each month.
3. As already pointed out, use sequential numbering for invoices, regardless if they are paid or not.
4. Have another table named `InvoicePayments` where you will store: `InvoiceId | PaymentDate` (and `Amount` if you want to enable partial payments per invoice feature).
5. Every so often (depends on how often you want to send reminders), go through `InvoicePayments` table, check for those that are due for longer than your policy and send notifications accordingly.

Comment: I don't think I have a need for the InvoicePayments table as partial payments will not be accepted, everything else is good. However, how should I handle late fees? (I'll come back with a more specific way on how these are calculated if needed)

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a software problem. Please, *please* go ask an accountant how invoices in your country are handled. It does not matter if it's nice database design or great software architecture, first and foremost it has to conform to your tax authorities rules and regulations.

As an example, even the thought of combining two invoices into one would make a tax accountant turn pale and silently slip away to a country without an extradition treaty in my jurisdiction.

If this is homework, great. Go with one option, let the teacher grade it and learn from it. If this is actual software, *go get a professional* and let them give you the *requirements*. You are a software developer, it's not a bad thing to have no idea how accounting works. That's not our job. But it *is* our job to ask for help instead of just winging it.

Collect requirements from a professional in accounting. *Then* think about your software.

Comment: This isn't really homework, nor is it "actual" software in the sense that it will matter irl if it will comply with tax rules or regulations. But I think you're right so I'll be meeting with their accountant and ask them to be more elaborate on how they want their invoices handled. +1 for the "But it is our job to ask for help instead of just winging it." :P